# HoRNDIS not working on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: tethering

The procedure to get an Android phone to tether the internet connection to a Mac is given on countless websites.

I followed the instructions provided on the official page (https://joshuawise.com/horndis) but nothing happens.
The connection is not recognised in the Network section of the System Preferences.

My machine runs a Mac OS 10.14.6 and I'm tethering from a Huawei P20 Lite.

Anybody got any piece of advice?

I've added a screenshot of the Network preferences.
[image: System Preferences - Network preferences]

Comment: Does not it show up at all in Network or show up and not work?  If it isn't there at all, have a look under *Security and Privacy* and see if it blocked there.

Comment: I connect my Huawei P20 Lite  via USB and choose the "Transfer Files" mode, as this is the one which allows tethering when connecting to another Win 10 machine. I have tried the other options, but the result's always the same: nothing shows up in the _Network_ preferences (see screenshot). Nothing appears in _Security and Privacy_ either...

Comment: Was the horndis installation successful? (In newer MacOSes it usually fails, and you would need to follow a specific procedure to make it successful)

Answer (score 1):

I was showing the application was blocked in Security and Privacy section. After allowing it, I could use tethering with my Andriod device.
However I do not see the kext file in Extensions, which seems strange.